# .NET CI Build Sometimes Failing

Tags: c#, build, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, devenv

#### How can I make this build setup work consistently?

I have a build setup which *sometimes* fails.

If I retry the build, it may or may not succeed.

There seems to be something wrong with my build environment.

#### Environment:

- GitLab CI Multi Runner
- Windows Server 2012
- Runner as admin user.

#### GitLab CI Multi Runner Config:

```
concurrent = 1

[[runners]]
  url = "http://gitlab.xxxxx.com/ci"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  tls-skip-verify = false
  tls-ca-file = ""
  name = "XXXXXXX"
  executor = "shell"
```

#### Solution:

- 2 C# Console Applications
- SQL Server 2014 Database
- C# Unit Test Project
- NuGet

  - EntityFramework

#### Build Output:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.7.2 (998cf5d)
Using Shell executor...

Running on XXXXXXX...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into 'C:\Multi-Runner\builds\db00f967\0\xxxxx-log-parser'...
Checking out 344bae64 as master...

devenv "Solution\xxxxx-log-parser.sln" /build Release

Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.24720.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Build started: Project: xxxxx-database, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /debug:pdbonly /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\xxxxx_database.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.SqlClrAttributes.cs"
1>  Loading project references...
1>  Loading project files...
1>  Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies...
1>  Validating the project model...
1>  Writing model to C:\Multi-Runner\builds\db00f967\0\xxxxx-log-parser\Solution\xxxxx-database\obj\Release\Model.xml...
1>  xxxxx-database -> C:\Multi-Runner\builds\db00f967\0\xxxxx-log-parser\Solution\xxxxx-database\bin\Release\xxxxx_database.dll
1>  xxxxx-database -> C:\Multi-Runner\builds\db00f967\0\xxxxx-log-parser\Solution\xxxxx-database\bin\Release\xxxxx-database.dacpac
2>------ Build started: Project: xxxxx-log-parser, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>  xxxxx-log-parser -> C:\Multi-Runner\builds\db00f967\0\xxxxx-log-parser\Solution\xxxxx-log-parser\bin\Release\xxxxx-log-parser.exe
3>------ Build started: Project: xxxxx-log-parser-tests, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
4>------ Build started: Project: xxxxx-log-processor, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

ERROR: Build failed with: exit status 255
```

Comment: Maybe it is a dependency problem inside your project? Does this error occur if you build single threaded?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try switching over to msbuild (this was using devenv).

Answer (score 2):

Switching over to **MSBuild** has resolved my issues.
I shouldn't have been using **devenv.exe**.

Comment: I don't have it with me anymore, but usage of MSBuild can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx).